How to store multiple parameters of an agent within one component in AnyLogic?
I'm working on a simulation model in AnyLogic and I need to manage 82 parameters for each agent, which are categorized under 15 distinct themes. To keep these parameters organized and easily accessible, I want to create a data structure where each theme contains its applicable parameters.
Is it possible to create such a hierarchical data structure in AnyLogic? For instance, can I define custom classes for each theme and then aggregate these within the agent? If so, I would appreciate some guidance or code snippets on how to implement this structure.
Creating 82 different parameters feels redundant and sloppy.

You are correct: for that many parameters, it would not be practical to use individual parameters.
Instead, create a java class, give it the fields you need and instantiate it as a single parameter in your agent type.
If this means nothing to you: Learn about java classes online, then try it in AnyLogic. There are special courses for AnyLogic users to learn this, also various online videos.
Also, LLMs are very capable of helping you with Java these days, worth a try.
